# VBA Rolling Mean

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA. I am trying to calculate the rolling means of a range, I certain my mistake is something very silly

```
Function Rolling_Mean(Prices as Range)

Dim window as Long, i As Integer, temp_sum as Long
Dim means() as Long

window = 10
temp_sum = 0
ReDim means(1 to 253)

For i = 1 to 253
    temp_sum = temp_sum + Prices(i)

    If i Mod window = 0 Then
        means(i) = temp_sum / 10
        temp_sum = 0
    End If
Next

Rolling_Mean = means

End Function
```

I keep getting an error or an array of 0s. I think my issue is how im trying to access the `Prices`. I am also wondering how to implement the syntax `AVERAGE(Prices(1) to Prices(10))` as that would help a lot as well.

This will be run in the sheet with `=Rolling_Mean(B2:B253)`

Comment: How large is the range Prices?  For a rolling average the number of results will depend on how many cells are in the input ( #inputs - (window-1) )    Are you calling this from a worksheet cell, or from VBA?

Comment: A screenshot of desired output with row numbers and column letters could help. The function will return an array of averages for every 10 cells in the price range. If that's what desired then while entering the formula in worksheet, select the range and enter formula with control+shift+enter. Also, this can be done through excel worksheet formula without VBA if you need average of last 10 cells in price range in every corresponding cell in other column.

Comment: Oops .. Correction The function will return an array of averages for last10 cells for every 10th cell in the price range, with other elements of the array kept null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me.  Added the window as a second parameter.

```vb
Function Rolling_Mean(Prices As Range, window As Long)
    Dim i As Long, sum As Double
    Dim means(), data
    
    data = Prices.Value 'assuming a single column of cells....
    ReDim means(1 To UBound(data, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        sum = sum + data(i, 1)
        If i >= window Then
            means(i, 1) = sum / window
            sum = sum - data(i - window + 1, 1) 'subtract value from trailing end of window
        Else
            means(i, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    Rolling_Mean = means
End Function
```

If your Excel version doesn't have "auto spill" then you'll need to enter it as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want, now I know VBA syntax a little better